# Timer callbacks not working

Tags: roscpp, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Previously working timers in some of my packages/nodes have stopped working. The roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Timers example doesn't work either as the timer callbacks never execute. The program aborts normally with ctrl-C from the spin function.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, Diamondback and an Acer AX3400 (AMD Athlon II). Internet searches haven't uncovered any other examples of this problem. Hints?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9405/timer-callbacks-not-working/) by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2011-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes! Bhaskara, your suggestion was very insightful.

I have been keeping fairly comprehensive notes during development and one of the last things I did before the problem occurred most recently was: "roslaunch erratic_description erratic_laser_wg_world.launch". I then killed the processes with ctrl-C from the terminal, but the nodes still show up in rxGraph as failed. Executing "rosnode cleanup" doesn't seem to fix the timer problem.

Following up on your suggestion, "rosparam get /use_sim_time" showed TRUE. "rosparam set /use_sim_time false" corrected the timer problem.

Thanks again for your suggested solution to an issue that could have continued to tease me for quite some time. (and may your karma points increase substantially)

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't reproduce this on 10.04 or 10.10 with diamondback:

```
% ./bin/timers
[ INFO] [1300163272.915589903]: Callback 1 triggered
[ INFO] [1300163273.015990217]: Callback 1 triggered
[ INFO] [1300163273.115590082]: Callback 1 triggered
[ INFO] [1300163273.216186940]: Callback 1 triggered
[ INFO] [1300163273.315749665]: Callback 1 triggered
```

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you possibly have the /use_sim_time parameter set to True, and no simulator or publisher to /clock running?

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7